# I'm SOO sick of error handling

Tags: json, swift, jwt

Json, xcode, swift 3, JWT. Im trying to find the value for "non_field_errors"

```
{
"non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to login with provided credentials."
]
}
```

I've been at this for hours. First I coded for 200 and 400 errors and now Im working on json and i just cant get it. heres my code

```
if let session_code = server_response["non_field_errors"] as? [Any:Object] {
```

But what now? I know I need to go deeper but how?

Comment: FYI - you want `as? [String]` since the `"non_field_errors"` represents an array of `String` (at least as far as I can tell from the sample JSON you posted).

Comment: I had that, changed it in the post because I thought that was where I was uspposed to start.

Comment: Try This `if let session_code = server_response["non_field_errors"] as? NSArray {`

Answer (score 0):

`non_field_errors` is an array of `String`s. So you have to fix the casting to:

```
if let session_codes = server_response["non_field_errors"] as? [String] { ... }
```

Comment: Right I found that out with research, so then what I have to do is unwrap it after that? self.error_message = session_error as? String? If session_error is session_code

Comment: I do not really understand your comment. You do not have to unwrap `session_code` in the if clause.

Comment: the print is ["Unable to login with provided credentials."], how do I get that to a string without []?

Comment: `non_field_errors` is an array. You can iterate over it `for error in sessionCodes`, grab the first `sessionCodes.first` or do whatever you want to do with the array.

Comment: @Denis It's an array. In any language you'd expect people to know how to use arrays. Just get the first element. I personally don't know swift but if this were C++ it would be `session_codes[0]`.